# Node var number but remove " " with Discord JS

Tags: javascript

i'm using Discord js but i got a problem.
I want to do the commmand:
/count 96400000
so it's will get the number 96400000

so 96400000 is the number i want to add in my var: var time = args[0];

now the number 96400000 is added to time
but i need it's working like this: Date.now() + 86400000
when i change 86400000 to time it's not working

my code:

```
const Discord = require("discordj.s")
const client = new Discord.Client()

client.on("ready", () => 
{
    console.log("Working");
};

client.on("message", message => 
{
    let cmd = message.content.split(" ")[0]
    cmd = cmd.slice(prefix.length)
    let args = message.content.split(" ").slice(1)
    
    if (cmd === "count") 
        {
            var time = args[0];
            message.delete()
            message.channel.send(Date.now() + time)
        }
};
```

thanks for your help !

Comment: Please can you provide more code - where did you define args?

Comment: yes on this

client.on("message", message => 
{
    let cmd = message.content.split(" ")[0]
    cmd = cmd.slice(prefix.length)
    let args = message.content.split(" ").slice(1)

};

Comment: Please edit your question to include that, It's harder to read in a comment due to formatting restrictions.

Comment: oh sorry, yes wait

Comment: Have you tried logging args to your console?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to make a type conversion from string to number, and then add it to `Date.now()`.

You can do this by applying `Number` to the variable `time`

```
client.on("message", message => 
{
    let cmd = message.content.split(" ")[0]
    cmd = cmd.slice(prefix.length)
    let args = message.content.split(" ").slice(1)

    if (cmd === "count") 
        {
            var time = args[0];
            message.delete()
            message.channel.send(Date.now() + Number(time))
        }
};
```